# Searching multiple sub strings with special character as marker

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like :

```
myStr = "abcd123[ 45][12] cd [67]"
```

I want to fetch all the sub-strings between '[' and ']' markers.
I am using findall to fetch the same but all i get is everything between firsr '[' and ']' last character.

```
print re.findall('\[(.+)\]', myStr)
```

What wrong am i doing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably be marked as duplicate, but the simple fix here would be to just make your dot lazy:

```
print re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', myStr)

[' 45', '12', '67']
```

Here `.+?` means consume everything until hitting *first*, or nearest, closing square bracket.  Your current pattern is consuming everything until the very *last* closing square bracket.

Another logically identical pattern which would also work is `\[([^\]+)\]`:

```
print re.findall('\[([^\]]+)\]', myStr)
```

Comment: can you please edit your question with a little explanation about what does the `?` change ?

Answer (score 1):

The `.+` is greedy and selects as much it can, including other `[]` characters.

You have two options: Make the selector non-greedy by using `.+?` which selects the *least* number of characters possible, or explicitly exclude `[]` from your match by using `[^\[\]]+` instead of `.+`.

(Both of these options are about equally good in this case. Though the "non-greedy" option is preferable if your ending delimiter is a longer string instead of a single character, since the longer string is more difficult to exclude.)

Comment: Actually, your second suggestion is probably "better" in the sense that it should work across almost every regex engine, whereas lazy dot may not work in every engine.